# Using the '-' sign in jQuery Selector gives error

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying the run the following code:

```
$(document).ready({

    $("#menu-nav a").hover(
         function () {
           $(this).css ( marginRight: '20px' );
         }, 
         function () {
            $(this).css ( marginRight: '10px' );
         }
     );



}); //end ready
```

But, my dreamweaver reports and error on the line `$("#menu-nav a").hover(`. Is it okay to use the selector as `#menu-nav a` or should it be something else ?

Comment: I use hyphens in IDs all the time.  What error is it giving?  Do you get the error in your browser, or just in DW?

Comment: I do not get error in thr browser. But, the jquery does't work.

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){` it should be

Comment: There's no need for jQuery for this

Comment: This can be done in pure CSS

Comment: Jan is right just use in css `#menu-nav a:hover{}` selector

Comment: "my dreamweaver reports and error" — Never describe something just as "an error". Always quote the complete error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is instead of this:

```
$(document).ready({
```

You need this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

I am sure you knew that, but it's easy to overlook since the error is shown to be in the following line.

---

**Another issue:**

I think you will also run into problems here:

```
 $(this).css ( marginRight: '20px' );
```

Per the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/), you should use this:

```
 $(this).css ('margin-right', '20px');
```

---

**An alternative:**

Here's one more thing, just to give a complete answer. As is noted in the comments, you really don't need jQuery at all for this, if you don't want to use it. Try this:

```
#menu-nav a:hover { margin-right: 20px; }
```

You can add whatever styles you want like that.

Answer (score 3):

In your example

```
$(document).ready({...});
```

should be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //...
});
```

And also change

```
$(this).css ( marginRight: '20px' );
```

to

```
$(this).css('marginRight','20px');
```

or

```
$(this).css({'marginRight':'20px'});
```

in both lines

Answer (score 2):

You don't pass an object, so you cannot use `property: value`, you can code:

```
$(this).css({ marginRight: '20px'});
```

or:

```
$(this).css( 'marginRight', '20px' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this convention to avoid getting lost and confused in a myriad of brackets and parenthesis:

```
$(document).ready(DocReady);

function DocReady()
{       
       // More code here
}
```

An advantage is that you can also call the DocReady function from a button click (maybe to test it).

Comment: Unless you use it on all levels (not just `DocReady`), there's not much benefit.

Comment: only constructors should be titlecased, not ordinary functions

Comment: @JanDvorak -  Conventions that can't be enforced are meaningless and useless.